# WPF Video Chat with SignalR

Tags: c#, wpf, signalr, webrtc

I have made a WPF application in which I have used SignalR for text chatting. Now I want to add audio and video chatting as well. I have searched a lot on this but I am unable to find a suitable and a good solution for this which uses SignalR to pass media stream. Can anybody please guide me what should I use on top of SignalR in a WPF application?

Comment: Do you want to use WebRTC or SignalR? WebRTC is Peer-to-Peer and a server is only needed for initial start up and tear down of the connection and does not have to stream media. Please clarify.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent I have hosted a SignalR server and using that as a central hub for all chat. So now I was thinking to use SignalR for video chat as well, but it doesn't have that functionality. So I thought it might be a good idea to use webrtc on top of it

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly, a WPF application would be outside of a browser and thus cannot use the Javascript API's provided by Firefox and Chrome and thus cannot use WebRTC. There is the native API but there is not a .net implementation of the API.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent So any good ideas what should I do?

Comment: Use the native api, import the native functions, or not use webrtc...